# Simple Lie algebra over ${\bf R}$

Tags: lie-algebras

As far as I know classification of simple Lie algebra over ${\bf C}$ in ${\rm gl}\ (n, {\bf C})$ is done.

And note that $$ {\bf R}^3_\wedge \otimes {\bf C} = {\rm sl}\ (2,{\bf C})$$

(all of $3$-dimensional simple Lie algebra over ${\bf R}$ are ${\bf R}^3_\wedge ,\ {\rm sl}\ (2,{\bf R})$)

So

**question** : Classification of simple Lie algebra over ${\bf R}$ in ${\rm gl}\ (n, {\bf R})$ is done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is it done, but there is a [quick proof (A. Knapp, 1996).](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-10/S0002-9939-96-03448-X/S0002-9939-96-03448-X.pdf)